# Find MAC Addresses of devices in range of Wifi router with programatically

Tags: openwrt

How can I programtically get the MAC address of WiFi router.
i want the command or the program in c which will list only the mac address of devices which are connected to the my WiFi router. it it possible to get when i know the IP address of the router?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the MAC of the WiFi router on which you are connected (or try to connect) is probably possible if you have access to low level network frame.

Now it looks you are indeed willing to get the MAC of *ALL* the devices connected to the WiFi router, which is another thing ! Unless the router has some building functionality that gives you this list (like an HTML summary, I don't know if openWrt provide this), I don't think by running a program in C on a client, you would be able to get the MACs of other connected clients !

But in case the router as the information in an html page (eg : from a remote administration), you might try to simulate login to administration, get this page then parse the page to get the MACs... from a C prog..

Taking your problem from another side, if you have a wireless adapter you can set in monitor mode, you could sniff the wireless traffic on the channel(s) opened by your targeted WiFi router, and list the distinct client connected. Have a look to BackTrack's ssidsniff ?